# new Date() gives me an advanced date when trying to set it to input

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to set the date to my datepicker with the following code.

```js
document.getElementById('selFecha').valueAsDate = new Date();
```

```html
<input type='date' id='selFecha'>
```

But it gives me the date of tomorrow. I'd say there's nothing wrong with the local date of my pc because I sended `new Date()` to the console and gave me the current date.

I solved it with the following:

```
var fecha = new Date;
var d = fecha.getDate();
var m = fecha.getMonth()+1;
var y = fecha.getFullYear();
if(d<10){
    d='0'+d;
}
if(m<10){
    m='0'+m;
}
var hoy = y+"-"+m+"-"+d;
document.getElementById('selFecha').value = hoy;
```

But I don't like it. What could be happening with the first code?

My timezone is -6. I tested in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Can you post a runnable snippet reproducing the error then we could more easily help you.

Comment: I am getting proper date. Have you checked your PC date and timezone.

Comment: Done. Do you get the current date? What's your time zone?

Answer (score 1):

Well, now this works. Thanks to ecg8 who post me a blog where it's explained.

```js
var f = new Date();
document.getElementById('selFecha').valueAsDate = new Date(f.getFullYear(), f.getMonth(), f.getDate(), 12);
```

```html
<input type='date' id='selFecha'>
```

The input date from HTML doesn't read the time zone, so you have to send the current day as argument to `new Date()` with help of another `new Date()` runned before.

The `12` is to especify an hour of the day (in order to avoid time-zone issues, apparently).

Answer (score 0):

.valueAsDate() will always give you the GMT date by default.
https://austinfrance.wordpress.com/2012/07/09/html5-date-input-field-and-valueasdate-timezone-gotcha-3/

Comment: Thanks. I suspected that it was the problem, but I had no idea how to fix it. I still think that feature should be improved.